# pandas - Allocate declining amount on rank

Tags: python, pandas

I have a set of data which is ranked.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['02/01/2019', '03/01/2019', '04/01/2019', '07/01/2019', '08/01/2019', '09/01/2019', '10/01/2019', '11/01/2019', '14/01/2019', '15/01/2019'],
               'VOD': [3, 2.3, 2, 1.8, 2, 4, 5, 4, 3, 1],
               'BBY': [0.9, 1, 1.2, 1, 1, 2.3, 2.4, 2.5, 3, 2.9],
               'STJ': [4, 4.2, 4.3, 4.4, 3.5, 3, 2, 1, 1.2, 2],
               'RBS': [0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.6, 1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 2]})

df1 = df.rank(1, ascending=False, method='first')
```

I have a figure of 1000 which I am trying to allocate across the 4 columns. However, the max allocation for each column is 40% of the 1000. Filled up from 1st ranked column first.

For instance the first row would look like:

```
available = 1000
max_allocation = 0.4

result = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['02/01/2019'],
                       'VOD': 400
                       'BBY': 200
                       'STJ': 400
                       'RBS': 0})
```

In this instance the max each column can have is 400 (1000*0.4). Being the highest ranked column, 'STJ' is filled first with 400. There is 600 left to allocate as this is more than the max 400 another 400 would be allocated. This time to VOD being the number 2 ranked column. There is then only 200 left - less than the max allocation of 400. The remaining 200 would be allocated to the 3rd highest ranked column - 'BBY'. There is nothing left to allocate to the RBS column.

I have looked at using a class then adjust the amount to allocate but it gets very complicated as the additional rows are added in. Numpy Where was another choice but i could not get it to deal with the declining amount available for allocation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def allocation(rank):
    return min(available * max_allocation, max(0, available - (rank - 1)* available * max_allocation))

pd.concat([df.Date, df1.applymap(allocation)], axis=1)
```

Result:

```
         Date    VOD    BBY    STJ    RBS
0  02/01/2019  400.0  200.0  400.0    0.0
1  03/01/2019  400.0  200.0  400.0    0.0
2  04/01/2019  400.0  200.0  400.0    0.0
3  07/01/2019  400.0  200.0  400.0    0.0
4  08/01/2019  400.0  200.0  400.0    0.0
5  09/01/2019  400.0  200.0  400.0    0.0
6  10/01/2019  400.0  400.0  200.0    0.0
7  11/01/2019  400.0  400.0    0.0  200.0
8  14/01/2019  400.0  400.0    0.0  200.0
9  15/01/2019    0.0  400.0  400.0  200.0
```

Comment: brilliant, thanks very much. Was getting very bogged down in OOP